# Locking color scheme between two visualizations

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I followed the instructions of this [post](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/create-scrolling-legend-unlimited-items) to create a cross table and convert it to a scrolling legend that links to a plot.

Both the plot and the cross table are sourced from the same data table that gets refreshed with new data from a data node every time the user executes the query. The schema remains the same.

I used the "Spotfire Categorical"  color scheme for both the plot and the crossTable so that their colors would match. However every time the query is executed and the data table is refreshed, the color scheme gets reset and I have to redefine the color scheme for the two visualisations again.

Is there a way to lock the color scheme between the two visualisations so that it stays the same even if the data table is refreshed?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!